# Download prompt from MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my mvc application I use ajax post  using jquery . example is shown below

```
  var postData = { recordID: selectedRecord };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: postData,
                url: '<%= Url.Action("LoadAudioPlayer", "Search") %>',
                success: function (result) { alert(result); },
                error: function (result) { alert('error'); }
            });
```

In the action making a virtual path of a .wav file . How can i make a download prompt into user
my action is shown below

```
  public string LoadAudioPlayer(string recordID,SearchModels searchModel)
    {
        //doing some operations
         path=getPath(); \\getting virtual path of the file

        return path;
    }
```

I can see the path cause i put an alert .I want to make a prompt to user wether he want to download the file or not. How can i handle it with jquery?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add in your success function  the opening of a new window (pop up) with your path as location. This will query from the client browser the file stored on your server and ask the client whether or not he wnats to download it.

```
var postData = { recordID: selectedRecord };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: postData,
                url: '<%= Url.Action("LoadAudioPlayer", "Search") %>',
                success: function (result) { window.open(result,'',''); },
                error: function (result) { alert('error'); }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

rather than doing this ajax query, which seems unnecessary, you could write:

```
window.location = '<%= Url.Action("LoadAudioPlayer", "Search") %>/' + recordID;
```

and your Action method could be changed to this to handle files that do not exist

```
public string LoadAudioPlayer(string recordID, SearchModels searchModel)
{
    //doing some operations
    var path = getPath(); //getting virtual path of the file

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        var fileName=getFileName();

        ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
            "attachment; filename=" + fileName)

        return File(path, contentType);
    }

    return new EmptyResult();   
}
```

Comment: Indeed. The browser will prompt for action (save or open) anyway. No need to add yet another prompt.

Comment: Also note that Kon's answer using a DownloadResult class would be nice for all future download operations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459451/download-prompt-from-mvc/5459527#5459527

Comment: @hunter.. I cant be sure if path is available or not.And i must use jquery for ajax because of some reason. .Thanx